# Transform all floats ending in .0 in a dict to int

Tags: python, dictionary

How can I transform all float values in a dict ending in .0 to an int? Is there an elegant solution for this?

```
 {
   '4061_dummy': {
     'mae': 278.86288346930246,
     'best_par': {
       'metric': 'minkowski',
       'weights': 'distance',
       'n_neighbors': 6.0
     }
   },
   '4181_fourier': {
     'mae': 604.05,
     'best_par': {
       'metric': 'l1', 
       'weights': 'distance', 
       'n_neighbors': 1.0
     }
   },
   '4905_fourier': {
     'mae': 610.8769965277778,
     'best_par': {
       'metric': 'minkowski',
       'weights': 'uniform',
       'n_neighbors': 24.0
     }
   },
   'time': 1.47
 }
```

My solution for this problem you can see in the following.

```
for i in a:
    if isinstance(a[i], dict):
        for key in a[i]["best_par"]:
            if isinstance(a[i]["best_par"][key], float):
                if int(a[i]["best_par"][key]) == a[i]["best_par"][key] and isinstance(a[i]["best_par"][key], float):
                    a[i]["best_par"][key] = int(a[i]["best_par"][key])
                    print(a[i]["best_par"][key])
```

Comment: Iterate over your dictionary, check if `x == int(x)` and if so, replace `x` with `int(x)`?

Comment: There seem to be three different steps needed: 1) walk the dict and find float values; 2) [check if the float is a whole number](/q/21583758/4518341); 3) convert it to int. Which part(s) do you need help with? Please [edit] to clarify. For more tips, see [ask].

Comment: `ctrl+h` replace all `".0"` with `""` in the file

Comment: @12944qwerty Brilliant solution! I'll transform the dict to str and then I can replace it like you said

Comment: @Chris the comparison would not work in all cases. Perhaps, it's safer to change the data to string and check the pattern `[0-9]+.0`.

Comment: Replacing all `".0"` with `""` would turn `604.05` into `6045`, would it not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recursive solution:

```py
def convert_integer_floats_to_ints(d):
    for key, val in d.items():
        if isinstance(val, float) and val == int(val):                
            d[key] = int(val)
        elif isinstance(val, dict):
            convert_integer_floats_to_ints(val)
```

Comment: Use `if isinstance(val, float) and val.is_integer():`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes, agreed, that would be better.

Answer (score 1):

the only solution i can think of:

```
for i in data.keys():
    if i!='time': data[i]['best_par']['n_neighbors'] = int(data[i]['best_par']['n_neighbors'])
```

Output:

```
{'4061_dummy': {'best_par': {'metric': 'minkowski',
   'n_neighbors': 6,
   'weights': 'distance'},
  'mae': 278.86288346930246},
 '4144_dummy': {'best_par': {'metric': 'l1',
   'n_neighbors': 4,
   'weights': 'uniform'},
  'mae': 116.66041666666666},
 '4181_fourier': {'best_par': {'metric': 'l1',
   'n_neighbors': 1,
   'weights': 'distance'},
  'mae': 604.05},
 '4331_fourier': {'best_par': {'metric': 'minkowski',
   'n_neighbors': 1,
   'weights': 'distance'},
  'mae': 305.13958333333335},
 '4555_fourier': {'best_par': {'metric': 'minkowski',
   'n_neighbors': 1,
   'weights': 'distance'},
  'mae': 888.1520833333333},
 '4583_fourier': {'best_par': {'metric': 'l1',
   'n_neighbors': 1,
   'weights': 'distance'},
  'mae': 601.28125},
 '4853_dummy': {'best_par': {'metric': 'minkowski',
   'n_neighbors': 2,
   'weights': 'distance'},
  'mae': 77.25801122256406},
 '4905_fourier': {'best_par': {'metric': 'minkowski',
   'n_neighbors': 24,
   'weights': 'uniform'},
  'mae': 610.8769965277778},
 'time': 1.47}
```

Answer (score -2):

It's quite straightforward.

```
for v in data.values():
    if isinstance(v,dict):
        v['best_par']['n_neighbors'] = int(v['best_par']['n_neighbors'])
```

This assumes you don't really need to troll through the deep structure LOOKING for such values.  That's harder.

Comment: This converts all floats to integers. Not the ones that are ending in `.0`

Comment: Look at his data.  The variable is called `n_neighbors`.  By its name, you can tell that's always going to be an integral value.  It's easy enough to detect, but in this particular case, unnecessary.  The OP has described his problem incorrectly.

Comment: It'll throw an error when reaching the 'time' key.

Comment: That's a valid concern.  I'll change that.